# Conditional formatting based on weekday

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, weekday

Column B contains days starting at 30-Oct and incrementing 1 day each cell. All the way down for about 3 years. How could I do a color scale through the days of the week. Monday starts at one color (say blue) Sunday ends at another color (say green), starts over at Monday (with blue again). Possible on the color scale setting? Only possible by setting up a formula based conditional for each day of the week? How could I make this work?

Comment: 7 rules 1 for each day.  using `=Weekday(a1) = 1` and so on.  The color scale only work on the data it colors and you would need a helper column to do the weekday calc and only that column would be colored.

Comment: @ScottCraner I don't think you need a helper column.

Comment: google conditional formatting and =text(B2,"DDD")